# Here Maps Navigation samples seem to be missing the Navigation Library

Tags: android, here-api

I am very new to Android development as well as to Here API.

I have downloaded the examples, registered and downloaded the Freemium explore sdk, and generated the required keys.

I can compile and run the examples in the latest/explore/android folder, however I cannot compile those examples in the examples/latest/navigate/android/Navigation folder. All Navigation samples complain that the navigation library is missing.

for example:

/home/ninja/AndroidStudioProjects/here-sdk-examples/examples/latest/navigate/android/Navigation/app/src/main/java/com/here/navigation/NavigationExample.java:37: error: package com.here.sdk.navigation does not exist
import com.here.sdk.navigation.ManeuverNotificationListener;

Is the Navigation library separated from the Explore and Lite libraries? If so, what is the simplest method of accessing this library to compile and run the examples?

Answer (score 0):

The 4.x Navigate edition is still in the closed beta testing phase. It is planned to go commercial during the second half of 2020. We do offer the Premium edition of the SDK, which including features like turn-by-turn and voice navigation. Please check if you can waiting till Q3 for the Navigate edition, and during the mean time please feel free to try the Premium edition. The Premium edition is included in our Freemium plan btw.