# Lack of Navigation Edition Here SDK for android

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

So I was looking for the examples on GitHub here for navigation:

https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/android/Navigation

Yet it does not work because it expects 4.x navigation library for the project to work.

It seems like someone else asked a very similar question to me here:

[Here Maps Navigation samples seem to be missing the Navigation Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243886/here-maps-navigation-samples-seem-to-be-missing-the-navigation-library)

It said to expect a commercial release for the Navigation SDK in latter half of 2020.

I was wondering what the status of the release is, since maybe it is released and I just happened to lost in where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The the Navigate Edition is released meanwhile. But for now, it is only available upon request. Please contact your HERE representative to receive access including a set of evaluation credentials.